# Many to Many triangle between three tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design, many-to-many

I am having three entities:

Student, Group, Class. All of them have many-to-many relationship:

- One student can attend many classes, and many classes may be assigned to one user.
- One student can be a part of many groups, and one group can contain many students.
- One group can be attended to many classes, and one class can have many groups.

[image]

I will need to make such queries:

- Get all classes that student is related to.
- Get the groups and students that are related to class.
- Get the classes and students that are related to specific group.

I've come up with a solution of three join-tables for each relationship, but I'm not sure about this use case - is SQL database is even suitable for this? Maybe I should research the NoSQL DB.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Does each member of each group (have to) attend the same  courses?

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні, each group member has to attend all courses that group is linked to, but it can also have unique ones, that are linked directly or through other groups

Comment: So, you can simplify your diagram. A student is a member of a group. A group attends a class. No need for the link between student and class - that is determined by group membership - you can check which student (has to) attend(s) which class by using SQL to `JOIN` student to group and then group to class!

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні - That sounds like an answer!  Comments should only be used for asking for clarification, or to leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post, or to add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated), or to provide site usage guidance.  See the [help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for details.